# Java - casting from unbounded wildcard to string

Tags: java, generics, set, instanceof, unbounded-wildcard

So, at first I had a line saying :

```
Object input = .... //some come code initialising it
if(input instanceof Set<String>) {
    doSomething(input);
}
```

However, since generic type information is erased at runtime, I cannot specify that it is a `Set<String>`but instead a unbounded wildcard `Set<?>`.
But I need to use this set for String related handling like appending to a JTextArea, so this unbounded wildcard type is not very useful when I require Strings to come out.

So, I tried this

```
Object input = .... //some come code initialising it
if(input instanceof Set<?>) {
    doSomething((Set<String>) input);
}
```

This cast gets it from unbounded to a string type (I am sure it will be of `Set<String>` if the input is a `Set`) but this isn't very safe is it? I get an error saying I could suppress the unchecked cast but I feel like there may be another way of approaching this. Any ideas?

EDIT: initialised `input` by serialising from an input stream from a server socket on private LAN ip.

Answer (score 1):

You can inspect your object to make sure that it only contains `String`s:

```
if(input instanceof Set<?> && ((Set<?>)input).stream().allMatch(x -> x instanceof String)) {
    doSomething((Set<String>)input);
}
```

You'll still have to suppress the warning. This is safer than your original, because if the set contains only `String`s (or is empty), it can *usually* be treated as a `Set<String>`. However, it is still rather unsafe, because, for example, you may have deserialized an empty `EnumSet`. An `EnumSet` needs to cast its elements to `Enum`s to get their `ordinal()`s, but a `String` can't do that! You may want to copy the set into your own set first:

```
if(...) {
    Set<String> input2 = new HashSet<>();
    input2.addAll((Set<String>)input);
    doSomething(input2);
}
```

This only iterates the elements `input`, which is less likely to blow up, and guards you from giving elements to `input` that it can't handle. Note that it's not just inserting that is unsafe, simply checking whether an item of the wrong type is in the set could blow it up.

Comment: It can't _really_ "be" a `Set<Integer>` after; with the verification that it only contains `String`s it effectively is a `Set<String>` for all intents and purposes, at least at the time `doSomething` is called. Of course, if the `Set` is retained on the outside, it's possible that an object of another type is added later.

Comment: @daniu If it's empty, `anyMatch` always gives `true`. In that case, it reveals nothing about what the set is meant for and it could "be" a `Set<Integer>` to someone else.

Comment: Yes, but my point was that after type erasure, the "intended" type is gone ("to someone else" is what I meant by "retained outside"). You can do `Set<Integer> set = new Set<Integer>(); Object o = set; Set<String> stringSet = (Set<String>) o;` and work with `stringSet` without ever running into any runtime problems after (which is the only danger of the cast).

Comment: @daniu That's not strictly true. An `EnumSet` wouldn't be very happy if you started shoving `String`s at it, and a `BitSet`-like `Set<Integer>` implementation would be similarly annoyed, yet this implementation cannot distinguish between such restrictive empty sets and unrestricted empty sets. But, I see your point.